# Как узнать стек технологий на котором писалось приложение в Play Market?

Tags: мобильные-приложения, playmarket

**Возможно** *ли* каким-либо путями ,,пронюхать" и увидеть на каком **стеке** **технологий** писалось то или иное приложение в play market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полностью узнать все tool'ы, языки я думаю почти невозможно.Так как всё это дело потом компилируется в байт-код. Но можно посмотреть внутренности (скомпилированные) через ES Проводник (Скачивать его надо с интернета, не из Play Market'а, так-как его убрали). И может быть, по расширениям файлов, папкам, и т.д можно будет понять язык или IDE.

Comment: X-Plore есть в гугл плей. Выполняет данную задачу даже легче